# Usage of multiple dicts versus a single dict of class instances

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm looking at some code that loads data in the following way:

```
idToFoo, idToBar, idToBaz = loadFlibbets()
```

Each of these is a dict between the id and a corresponding data value.

This is then used in a way similar to:

```
for id in idToFoo:
    foo = idToFoo[id]
    bar = idToBar[id]
    baz = idToBaz[id]
    # process flibbet
```

My OO pattern of thinking tells me that this code would be easier to understand if I were to define a class that held the `foo`, `bar` and `baz` properties as fields, and then changed to something resembling:

```
flibbets = loadFlibbets()

for flibbet in flibbets:
    # process flibbet using flibbet.foo, flibbet.bar and flibbet.baz
```

Which is the more Pythonic approach? I'm relatively new to Python and I've inherited some code that I find quite hard to reason about, but it may just be that I need to think differently. Would someone with more Python experience comment?

Comment: Sounds like you should make flibbet a `namedtuple`

Comment: @gnibbler, is that recommendation based upon style, performance or both?

Comment: Your gut doesn't know a thing about performance. Your profiler, on the other hand, does. More importantly, it can also tell you whether to worry about performance *at all* to begin with, potentially saving you a lot of time if you listen to it ;) So, do you have any data indicating (1) a performance problem and (2) a performance problem with this particular piece of your code?

Comment: @delnan, I'm with you on the gut not knowing. I'm actually running with IronPython and the profiler shows more about the guts of the .NET DLR than actual Python instructions. There's a heck of a lot of Dictionary lookups, but that may just be the DLR implementation. I'l edit the question to de-emphasise the performance aspect. Mostly I would like to know whether the code I'm looking at (which was written by someone else) is common practice in Python or not. It may be that I'm trying to shoe-horn my OO thinking where it doesn't fit.

Comment: @delnan, and yes, I have a performance problem (though maybe somewhere else) as the process takes around 10 minutes to complete :) However I think making the code clearer will allow for the real performance gains of simplifying the algorithm.